# Should I place comma after mentioning what the secondary character did and after mentioning the person's title?

Tags: grammar, email

Take the following message as an example:

Here I am talking to 'Mr. David' who is an executive chef regarding an application for 'Head Chef' where 'Ms. Jolie' told me (by email) that 'Mr. David' will call me the last week but didn't. Its the end of the week and I would send him this message to his number that she gave me to get some feedback:

> Dear Mr. David,
>
> My name is {name}, I was told by Ms. Jolie who gave me this
> number, that you, the Executive chef, will call me anytime this week
> regarding my application for "head chef".

My question, are the commas here added correctly? or something is out of place?

Comment: Comma placement is often just a matter of personal style. You could put a comma after Ms Jolie's name. We're not supposed to supply a proofreading service, buy why are you telling Mr David what his job is? He already knows. Leaving that bit out would reduce the number of other commas in the sentence.

Comment: Are you writing an email? "Gave me this number" sounds like a text message, then you wouldn't need Dear. You don't need "Head Chef" or 'head chef', but just Head Chef.

Comment: @KateBunting the message is an example to get to my point. and I not asking for a proofreading service. but a way to compose that message better (if possible)

Comment: By 'proofreading' we mean pointing out errors and suggesting how you could improve your writing. This forum is only supposed to answer questions about individual words or grammatical issues. Yes, it is very common to put a comma before a phrase explaining who someone is or what they have done.